# Triggering VueJs $watch from browser's console not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this `main.js` file that bootstraps my Vue application.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

var model = {
  a: 1,
  name: 'Abdullah'
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: model,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  },
  watch: {
    a: function(val, oldVal) {
      console.log('new: %s, old: %s', val, oldVal)
    }
  }
});

app.a = 23; //This triggers the watch function
```

Inside my view instance i am watching any changes on data `a`.

Any change on `a` should trigger the `watch` and write to console. This `watch` works fine when i trigger it by changing the value of `a` from within the `main.js` file like so `app.a=23;` but the same doesn't work when i trigger it from the browsers console.

How can i trigger `watch` from the browser's console whenever `a` is changed?

**PS:** I have just started with `VueJS`.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to trigger this from the console? If you need to test it you could bind the property to an input field and check that values are shown in the console.

Comment: You got me! i just wanted to test it. But why is `$watch` not accesible on the console?

Comment: Do you even access `app` from the console? Seems you are using webpack so you have to first make the app accessible from the console: `global.app = app` and now if you try to change `app.a` it should work.

Comment: `app` is accesible from the console.

Comment: @Slim : By accesible i mean when i log `app` i get the the complete html which is bind to it.

Comment: It must return the Vue instance not the html it is bound to..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple issues at play here.

First you have a `div` with an `id` of `app`. All browsers make HTML elements with an `id` attribute available as global variables. So, you have a global variable called `app` that points to the `div` with the `id` of `app`.

Second, You capture the result of `new Vue()` in a variable called `app`. However, since you are pretty clearly using a build system (because you are using `import`) *that* `app` is not available in the global scope because pretty much all build systems wrap their compiled javascript in a closure.

The result being the `app` you want to change is not accessible to you, but it looks like it is because there is a completely separate variable called `app` available to you in the global scope.

If you want to do what you are trying to do, I recommend you change your script to this:

```
window.myApp = new Vue(...)
```

Then you will be able to go to your console and type

```
myApp.a = 23
```

And see the results you expect.